# GetFileAsync then invoke Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync by reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, windows-phone-8

I am developing a windows phone app and I target it to 7.1, so it can run on a wp7 and wp8 device.
If the  apps run on a wp8 device, I would like to run this code:

```
public async void DefaultLaunch2a()
{
    // Path to the file in the app package to launch
    var file1 = await ApplicationData
        .Current
        .LocalFolder
        .GetFileAsync("webcam-file.jpg");

    if (file1 != null)
    {
        // Launch the retrieved file
        var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file1);

        if (success)
        {
            // File launched/y
        }
        else
        {
            // File launched/n
        }
    }
    else
    {
       // Could not find file
    }
}
```

A launcher file type (to open an image). I am trying do it by reflection, but I have some kind of a problem.

```
String name = "file1.jpg";
Type taskDataType2 = Type.GetType("Windows.Storage.StorageFolder, Windows, "
                                  + "Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, "
                                  + "PublicKeyToken=null, "
                                  + "ContentType=WindowsRuntime");

MethodInfo showmethod2 = taskDataType2.GetMethod("GetFileAsync", 
                                                 new Type[] 
                                                 { 
                                                     typeof(System.String) 
                                                 });
showmethod2.Invoke(taskDataType2, 
                   new System.String[] { name });
```

This code throws an exception `TargetException: Object does not match target type`
 - when I invoke the method.

What is wrong? Is there anyone that has already tried to write the code above using reflection? 
The goal is to read an image file from the device-store and then launch `Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync`.
If the code is running on a wp8 device I want to do something like mangopollo.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies within the fact, that you should invoke the method on the instance of `taskDataType2` not on the object representing the type. `taskDataType2` is not an instance of `Windows.Storage.StorageFolder`, it is an instance of the `Type` type. Try something like this:

```
Type taskDataType2
    = Type.GetType("Windows.Storage.StorageFolder, Windows,"
                   + " Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral,"
                   + " PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime");

MethodInfo showmethod2 = taskDataType2
    .GetMethod("GetFileAsync", new[] { typeof(string) });

object taskDataInstance = taskDataType2
    .GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)
    .Invoke(null);    

String name = "file1.jpg";
showmethod2.Invoke(taskDataInstance, new[] { name });
```

This is simplified to the case when the type can be instantiated with a parameterless constructor. Otherwise you should call [`GetConstructor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getconstructor.aspx) with appropriate parameters instead of `Type.EmptyTypes`.

Note that this is not a [recommended](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227230?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) way to retrieve `StorageFolder` instance:

> Typically, you access `StorageFolder` objects as the result of asynchronous method and/or function calls. For example, the static method `GetFolderFromPathAsync` returns a `StorageFolder` that represents the specified folder.